# matplotlib multiple line plot color according to reference value

Tags: python, matplotlib

If i have a dataset:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
y = np.array([np.random.randn(10) for k in range(100)])
plt.plot(y)
```

[image: plot of random numbers]

And a corresponding vector of categorical values:

```
x = np.array([['nr1', 'nr2'] for k in range(5)]).reshape(10,1)
```

How do i color according to whether the y is `'nr1'` or `'nr2'`?
It's also ok if pandas `plot()` function have an easy way.

It should preferably be scalable so there can be more than two groups in x.

Comment: So, you want to plot `y` with 2 colors based on `x` i.e. if `x[0]` is nr1 then plot `y[0]` with a particular color, and if `x[1]` is nr2 then plot `y[1]` with a different color?

Comment: Yes exactly. :) Or i guess the color of x[1] for y[:,1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Edit: This already includes the comment and is working for any number of categories.*

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
y = np.array([np.random.randn(6) for k in range(100)])

x = np.array([['nr1', 'nr2', 'n3'] for k in range(2)]).reshape(6)

uniques, inverse = np.unique(x, return_inverse=True)
c = mpl.cm.Set1(inverse)

for i in range(y.shape[1]):
    plt.plot(y[:,i], color=c[i])
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice! I forgot to mention that the number of categories can be any number, so that np.unique(x).shape is unknown